# Variable references in Intel style inline assembly and AT&T style, C++

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, intel, inline-assembly

I need to compile some assembly code in both Visual Studio and an IDE using G++ 4.6.1. The -masm=intel flag works as long as I do not reference and address any variables, which however I need to do.

I considered using intrinsics, but the compiled assembly is not optimal at all (for instance I cannot define the sse-register to be used and thus no pipe optimization is possible).

Consider these parts of code (inte style assembly):

```
mov       ecx, dword ptr [p_pXcoords]
mov       edx, dword ptr [p_pYcoords]
movhpd    xmm6, qword ptr [oAvgX]
movhpd    xmm7, qword ptr [oAvgY]
movlpd    xmm6, qword ptr [oAvgX]
movlpd    xmm7, qword ptr [oAvgY]
```

where p_pXcoords and p_pYcoords are doublde* arrays and function parameters, oAvgX and oAvgY simpled double values.

Another line of code is this, which is in the middle of an assembly block:

```
movhpd    xmm6, qword ptr [oAvgY]
```

in other words, I need to access variables and use them within specific sse registers in the middle of the code. How can I do this with AT & T syntax, best: can I do this with a g++ compiler using the -masm flag?

Is there any way at all using one assembly code for both VS and a g++ 4.6.1 based compiler

Comment: Your hand-written asm isn't optimal either.  This appears to be broadcasting `qword ptr [oAvgX]` into both halves of `xmm6` inefficiently, with a false dependency on the old value there.  Normally you'd load + shuffle, like `movsd xmm6, [oAvgX]` which doesn't merge with the old val, then `unpcklpd xmm6, xmm6`. Or SSE3 `movddup xmm6, [oAvgX]`, but at least start with `movsd` instead of `movhpd` / `movlpd` load+merge. Or if X and Y are adjacent, one load and two shuffles are possible, like `movups` load then `pshufd xmm7, xmm6, 0x??` and `unpckhpd`.  But with SSE3, 2x `movddup` is probably best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly tell GCC which SSE register to use for each variable:

```
register __m128i x asm("xmm6");
```

But I guess VS does not support that.  (I am also a little surprised you need it for decent performance.  Register assignment and instruction scheduling are two of the most basic things an optimizing compiler knows.  You sure you enabled optimization :-) ?)

I would probably just write two functions, one using intrinsics, and one using asm for whichever compiler does not know how to schedule instructions properly.

Comment: Greetings and thanks for the reply. Yes, I used -O2 and even the -msse2 flag, but the intrinsics sorta put everything sequentially into xmm0 when using _mm_loadu_pd for instance. One specific question: how would you translate the one line given above in the middle of an assembly block to AT & T style? I do not intend using asm(...) individually for each line when having larger blocks.

Comment: You have to use "constraints" to specify inputs, outputs and clobbers (side-effects). See the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Note that if you have larger blocks, chances are you shouldn't be using inline asm - just write a function in a separate asm file. That way you might be able to use the same code (calling convention permitting).

Comment: Greets Jester, yes, I know about the constraints, but I think the idea of separate .s files is better. Thanks, Andy

Comment: Hi again Nemo, assigning variables to registers seems to work only when optimization is turned on (O2 for instance) in g++ 4.6.1. However, using this in combination with optimization and intrinsics, everything is just fine. Thanks, G.